Cannot send property of fetched data to innerHTML
I am somewhat new to JavaScript and wanted to fetch sensor data from a remote site and display it on a local page in a DIV element.
There are two properties of the fetched data: name and value.
When it gets to the line in the script:
document.getElementById('sensorValue').innerHTML = data.value;
the console displays a error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')".
A few lines above, the script successfully fetches and sends data.value to the console.log.
I cannot figure out how to get the data.value into the DIV element using innerHTML.

    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>fetch & innerHTML test</h2>

    <div id='sensorValue'></div>

    <script>

        fetch("https://example.com/filename.php?apikey=1567477555629&setting1=1" )
        .then( response => {

        if( ! response.ok ) {
            throw new Error("Could not fetch resource")
        }
        return response.json()
        })

        .then( data => console.log(data.value))   

        .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('sensorValue').innerHTML = data.value;
        })
        .catch( error => console.error(error));

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

I changed the line in question to assign a string instead of data.value:
document.getElementById('sensorValue').innerHTML = "Test";
and it filled the DIV with id='sensorValue' successfully.
Thank you for your insight!

This question is similar to: Why is my response data undefined when sending a fetch()?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This callback returns undefined:
.then(data => console.log(data.value))

So in the next callback data will be undefined:
.then(data => {
  document.getElementById('sensorValue').innerHTML = data.value;
})

Either remove that first one, or combine the two operations:
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  document.getElementById('sensorValue').innerHTML = data.value;
})

Or, if you want to keep them separate, return the value:
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.value);
  return data;
})


The combination of the two operations did the trick! Thanks so much, David!!!
